# ckeditor 3 find element by attribute

Tags: ckeditor

using CKEditor 3.x

I'm capturing the "saveSnapshot" event on the editor to bind an "click" event to divs that have special attributes eg: (data-type="notes").  I have found only document.getById(). I can't use ids because of possible duplicates in the document.  Is there any way to search by anything other than id?

I've also tried using the filter but failed to bind the "click" event that way (using extjs and jquery)..it a different type of element object (internal)

```
editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
                {
                    elements :
                    {
                        div : function( element )
                        {
                            if (element.attributes.data-notes) {}

                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.$.getElementsByClassName("ponymagic"); 
arr[0];
arr[0].onclick = function() {console.log("Magical pony time")};
```

You might have to loop that. It's not optimal, I know, but it's a start until you find a better option if one is needed.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction and letting me know of the "$" method. The sdk gives an example of getting the "native dom" object from an internal element by simply calling element.$  but its undefined.